# Runtime error: code size to deposit exceeds maximum code size

Tags: web3.py, python, solc

I'm using solc_version version 0.8.16, which i checked is installed, but when i'm trying to deploy the contract getting error `Runtime error: code size to deposit exceeds maximum code size`. While using truffle it works fine.

```
_compiled_contract = compile_files(
        contracts_to_compile, output_values=["abi", "bin"], optimize=True, optimize_runs=200, evm_version="byzantium", solc_version="0.8.16")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the optimizer when compiling your contract. This will try to remove any unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of a contract is 24.576 kb. Make sure to check your contract size using this [hardhat tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hardhat-contract-sizer)

There are multiple ways to reduce the size, find more details in this [post](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/downsizing-contracts-to-fight-the-contract-size-limit/)

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I was using optimization but after going though you reply i realized i was doing blunder BCZ that increases the gas costs for running the functions